# Executablejar in jar using maven Shade plugin

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am new to Java world. I have used dependencies Math.jar and Special.jar  and I have written a Main Method. Those Math.jar and Special.jar were created from terminal so they don't have version number. While building the project it shows error that version number not found for dependencies. So what should my pom.xml contain. Also if there is any step by step tutorial to create jar inside jar and make it executable it would be of much help. Also if any different tool is available please do explain. Thank you in advance. This is the part it shows errors as the jars do not have version number that 1.0 is a random number I chose. Also I am using Intellij idea / Eclipse  / terminal. So any solution that can be implemented by IDE or terminal would do

```html
'
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>Math</groupId>
    <artifactId>Math</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>Special</groupId>
    <artifactId>Special</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>

</dependencies>`
```

The directory structure I need is

A.jar  (Contains below files ) 
`Math.jar
      Special.jar
      MainMethod.class
      META-INF`

the user would run just A.jar and all the dependencies would be included in A.jar.

My rest of pom.xml is

```html
<build>
  <finalName>Workspace</finalName>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3</version>
      <executions>
        <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
        <execution>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>shade</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <transformers>
              <!-- add Main-Class to manifest file -->
              <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                <mainClass>MainMethod</mainClass>
              </transformer>
            </transformers>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>MainMethod</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: I think it might make sense to split your question into two separate ones: One on how to depend on files and one for any problems you have with the maven-shade-plugin.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maven strongly advocates the philosophy that all dependencies of an application should be in a repository and being fetched from there. As a consequence, the support for file-dependencies is only rather basic. Effectively, you have two options

#### System dependency

Declare a system dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>Math</groupId>
  <artifactId>Math</artifactId>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>path/to/math.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

I think this should work without specifying a version. Please note that system dependencies have been deprecated by the Maven people. So, this is not a future-proof solution.

#### Install dependencies to local repository

The other option is to install the jars into your local Maven repository with the following command:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file -Dfile=Math.jar -DgroupId=math -DartifactId=math -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

This will register the given jar with the provided coordinates in your local repository so that you can the refer to it as you did in your pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>Math</groupId>
  <artifactId>Math</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

#### Better solutions

I would consider the two solutions to be more a kind of workaround than an actual solution. As a long term solution, I suggest that you build your dependencies with Maven as well. If you rather want to continue to depend on files directly, I suggest to switch to ant or Gradle as these build tools treat file dependencies as a legitimate way to declare a dependency more than Maven does.

### Jar-in-Jar

A jar-in-jar is usually called a fat jar or an uber-jar. To me your declaration of the maven-shade-plugin looks okay. And I think it should give you what you except (I assume `mainMethod` is the class that contains your `public static void main(String[] args)` method and you do not have any packages).

Comment: Guys Thanks for your reply I have tried to  implement one jar plugin but it has error

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by "implement one jar plugin". What was your error message?

Comment: What it basically said was that One jars repos was changed so cannot resolve its dependency in pom.xml. Any ways that problem has been solved and my project is working great. Thank you .